# Error en el else en python

Tags: python, else

No entiendo por qué me sale error en el else. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceré.

```
x = 1+4*3+8/2*4+5**2 
if x%2==0:
 x=x+1
print(x)
else:
x=x+2
print(x)
```

Comment: cual es el error? Por ahora, ese código está mal indentado y no hace lo que esperas... si lo copiaste tal cual, el print(x) está por fuera del if y el else no tiene un if que le corresponda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en Python, la identación no es opcional, un código con errores de identación, es un código que no funciona (en el mejor de los casos).

```
x = 1 + 4 * 3 + 8 / 2 * 4 + 5**2 
if x % 2 == 0:
    x = x + 1
    print( x )  
else:
    x = x + 2
    print( x )
```

Esta es la forma correcta de identar tu código, a lo que está dentro del ***if*** o del ***else*** se le aplica una sangría.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Un placer maestro!!!